# Trouble in finding instances of values of variables that satisfy an inequality

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

Consider the following mathematical expression with complex numbers (phasor) and two variables (lambda and ia2):

```
0.10237519423935033 E^(-((0. + 5944.02363388283 I)/\[Lambda])+1/200 (-15 + 58.3 Log[0.493827 ia2]))
```

I make the absolute value of this expression and set an inequality like the following:

```
 Norm[0.10237519423935033` E^(-((
 0.` + 5944.02363388283` I)/\[Lambda]) + 
1/200 (-15 + 58.3` Log[0.493827` ia2]))] > 0
```

Then I am trying to find the individual instances of lambda and ia2 with the given range that
satisfy the inequality.

```
FindInstance[{Norm[
0.10237519423935033` E^(-((
   0.` + 5944.02363388283` I)/\[Lambda]) + 
  1/200 (-15 + 58.3` Log[0.493827` ia2]))] > 0, 1.52 < \[Lambda] < 1.58, 0.1 < ia2 < 40}, {\[Lambda], ia2}]
```

However, the following error pops up: FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. >>

Can anyone help me fixing this error? Thanks.

Comment: although the values of ia2 = 25; and \[Lambda] = 1.55; clearly give the absolute value of this expression 0.1976 which is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahem, the norm of a Complex is always greater that zero ...

```
FindInstance[{Abs[ 0.10237519423935033` E^(-((0.` +  5944.02363388283` I)/λ) + 
                 1/200 (-15 + 58.3` Log[0.493827` ia2]))] > 0, 
            1.52 < λ < 1.58, 0.1 < ia2 < 40}, {λ, ia2}, 10]

(* {{λ -> 1.52188, ia2 -> 13.}, 
    {λ -> 1.52314, ia2 -> 2.33333},
    {λ -> 1.53602, ia2 -> 15.6667}, 
    {λ -> 1.53614, ia2 -> 18.3333},
    {λ -> 1.55161, ia2 -> 20.},
    {λ -> 1.55508, ia2 -> 10.6667},
    {λ -> 1.56114, ia2 -> 21.3333}, 
    {λ -> 1.56485, ia2 -> 2.66667}, 
    {λ -> 1.56719, ia2 -> 20.3333}, 
    {λ -> 1.56761, ia2 -> 8.}}*)
```

Comment: "greater than *or equal to*". ;)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. *"generally speaking"*:)

Comment: I have got one more question relating to it. If you want to set up the step size in the range of my given variable, how to modify the code? I mean,   for 1.52 < λ < 1.58, if I want to fix the step size to 0.01, how to modify the above-mentioned code?  Thanks.